# Making a applescript address book

Tags: text, applescript

I'm trying to make an applescript that will open a document and add whatever i type into the text box to the document and then saves it to a path. When I try to save it, it just says "could not save x because the file does not exist."

Here is my code

```js
display dialog "username" default answer ""
set the target_username to the text returned of the result
display dialog "password" default answer "" with hidden answer
set the pass to the text returned of the result
if target_username is "Plasma" and pass is "Sship" then
    display dialog "Welcome! Please select a function!" buttons {"Add address", "View address"}
    if button returned of result is "Add address" then
        set booka to text returned of (display dialog "rers!" default answer "")
        tell application "TextEdit"
            activate
            make new document
            set text of document 1 to booka

            delay 10
            set thePath to "/Users/Cameron/Desktop/"
            set thedoc to document 1
            set thetitle to "food"
            save thedoc in (thePath & thetitle)
        end tell
    else
        display dialog "no"
    end if
else
    display dialog "no"
end if
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The script bellow can save in txt file.

```
set booka to "my string" -- set booka variable just for testing !
tell application "TextEdit"
activate
make new document
set text of document 1 to booka
set thePath to "Users:Cameron:Desktop:food.txt"
tell document 1 to save in file thePath
end tell
```

Comment: Script is working for me, of course replacing 'Cameron' by by own user name. Are you sure your user is 'Cameron' ? (that's the only thing I can't test)

Comment: By any chance would you know how to open up the same document and write another thing?

Comment: use 'open' instruction in a 'tell TextEdit' bloc, set your new text and save again. However, if the purpose is just to write text on a txt file, you do not need to use TextEdit. look for 'read' and 'write' commands in Applescript.